# Can sigwaitinfo() wait for a super set of the process signal mask?

Tags: c, signals, posix

I'm tring to correctly emulate [sigwait()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigwait.html), [sigwaitinfo() and sigtimedwait()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigtimedwait.html) for [Jehanne](http://jehanne.io), but I can't grasp the expected behavior when multiple signals selected by the `set` argument are concurrently sent to a process waiting in one of these functions.

For example, the first signal will cause the sigwaitinfo to return, filling the `info` argument.
But what about the second signal? As far as I can see, if the second signal is not blocked (it's not included in the process signal mask), the process should receive it, interrupting the first signal management, reducing the advantage of using these group of functions.

This makes me wonder if the `set` provided to these functions must always be a subset of the process signal mask or if there is simply something else I'm missing.

In other words: the Linux manual page states that

> In **normal usage**, the calling program blocks the signals in set via a prior call to sigprocmask(2) (so that the default disposition for these signals does not occur if they become pending between successive calls to sigwaitinfo() or sigtimedwait()) and does not establish handlers for these signals.

I'd like to know it this "normal usage" is the only correct usage of this API, or there are proper use cases where the `set` argument contains more signals than the process signal mask.

Comment: Based on experience, I would say that if a handler did not complete while another *same* event occurs, then the 2nd one is queued, and will start *after* the first one completes.

Comment: @RingØ: I'm afraid that POSIX signals do not count among "event queues". At least if sigprocmask() is not used to block them. However, if you can show this behavior with a small C test that I can run on Linux and NetBSD, I would count it as a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

This small code is an attempt to answer your comment, and seems to work as expected on Ubuntu

```
// ctrl-c handler
void cc(int s) {
    static int count = 0;
    printf("Entering cc %d\n", ++count);
    sleep (5);
    printf("Leaving cc %d\n", count);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    signal(SIGINT, cc); // ctrl-c

    int n = 10; // leave after 10 ctrl-c
    while (n--) {
        pause();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> is caught and `cc` is executed. `cc` increments and prints a number, and we expect the same number to be displayed when leaving the function. If `cc` is reentered due to another <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> before its execution completed (sleep 5) we'd have something like

```
Entered cc 1
Entered cc 2
Leaving cc 2
Leaving cc 2
```

It's not recommended to do some I/O like `printf` within a signal handler, but in our tiny case there is no sharing violation, and even though we'd have some *stdout* buffering, the "Leaving text" would eventually be similar to the above, if `cc` was reentered.

But that didn't happen. Pressing another <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> while `cc` is sleeping does seem to have that second event pending somewhere (only 1 event seems to be kept). `sleep()` might have a special behavior? In that case, anyway, `cc` would be reentered *just* after the sleep, and show the unwanted behavior above.

Another notable behavior is `pause()` in main. If another <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> is pressed while one is "sleeping", this 2<sup>nd</sup> one is executed within the same "pause" (something like `while(event) { process(event); }` ; this behavior is shown by the number of <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> that have to be done to leave the program: should be 10, but it's actually 10 + number of times the key was pressed while a previous one was being processed.

Not sure that works on your system, and with any event, though.

Comment: While your post does not actually answer the question (that is about sigwait, sigwaitinfo and sigtimedwait), I have to thank you because you challenged my understanding of the standard and proved that it might be wrong. 
GNU Libc actually block the signal during the signal handler invocation: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Blocking-for-Handler.html  
I'm unable to find reference to such behavior in the POSIX documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on what you mean by "correct."

The normal usage is the only sensible usage.

Abnormal use is permissible in the sense that it won't court undefined behavior.  It is also pointlessly, dangerously complex.  Your implementation will have some algorithm for dispatching two pending signals for a process which is `sigwait`ing both, SIG_IGNoring neither, and blocking at most one.*  It's doubtful that that process has been designed correctly, however.

* Per POSIX-1.2008's *Signal Concepts*, ["[t]he order in which multiple, simultaneously pending signals ... are delivered to or accepted by a process is unspecified"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04), assuming non-realtime signals.

Comment: For correct I mean POSIX compliant. @RingØ showed an interesting (and to me completely unexpected) behavior that occurs on Linux. However it's related to `signal`, not `sigwait` and friends.

Comment: @GiacomoTesio , `signal` (on Linux) blocks the signal which trips the handler during handler execution (and it should not be used because of inflexibility and historical vagaries — use `sigaction` instead).  Additionally, ordinary UNIX signals do not queue, so only one at a time can be pending.  That I think explains @RingØ 's behavior.

Comment: The point about @RingØ 's behavior is whether it's a Linux specific or a POSIX dictated behavior. Also, AFAIK, ordinary UNIX signals do not queue, so only one **of each number** can be pending at any time. However, as far as I understood the doc, you can have several pending non-realtime signal with different numbers (and their delivery order will be unspecified). Is this wrong?

Comment: Yes, you can have e.g. USR1 and HUP and TERM all pending at the same time.  Do you want to open a separate question?